# Is it possible to override the all() method of Model or Polymodel to include a filter?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm working on a large project that was written (and abandoned) by someone else and need a way to make every call to .all() for a specific model check a Boolean I added.  There are literally thousands of calls through-out the project so I was looking for a way to avoid rewriting them all.

My thought was to override the .all() method, calling the parent .all() with a filter.  This is my first time working with Google App Engine, so I've been doing a lot of guess work.

I thought I could start with something like this:

```
class Bob(polymodel.PolyModel):
    stuff = db.StringProperty()
    active = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    def all(self, keys_only=False):
        super(Bob,self).all()
```

but when I try to call like this:

```
joes = Bob.all()
    for joe in joes:
        self.response.write(joe.active)
```

I get this:

*TypeError: unbound method all() must be called with Bob instance as first argument (got nothing instead)*

This is my first post on stackoverflow so I hope I've done this correctly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION** (added later)

```
class Bob(db.Model):
    stuff = db.StringProperty()
    active = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    @classmethod
    def all(cls, keys_only=False):
        if keys_only == True:
            qry = super(Bob,cls).all(keys_only=True)
            qry.filter('active =', True)
            return qry
        else:
            qry = super(Bob,cls).all(keys_only=False)
            qry.filter('active =', True)
            return qry
```

Comment: Your indentation on your solution is incorrect.  Also why are you putting the `if keys_only=True:` condition in.  Just pass keys_only into the all() call.  ie `all(keys_only=keys_only)`  as per my answer.  Less code to test and keep up to date.

Comment: sorry, just now came back to this... it didn't paste in correctly and i didn't notice at the time.  I'll fix the indentation.  for some reason though, your solution wasn't working although I thought it should as well.  the if block was my work-around for your method not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you have a basic python class/method issue.  As the error says `TypeError: unbound method all() must be called with Bob instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

You are calling `all()` on a class not an instance but you have defined the overridden `all()` as an instance method.

It should be

```
@classmethod
def all(cls, keys_only=False):
    qry = super(Bob,cls).all(keys_only=keys_only)
    qry.filter(<some filter>)
    return qry
```

Also note in your code you are not returning anything.  all() returns a query object that you can apply futher filters too.

I wouldn't override all and apply filters  because you will effectively prevent you from ever being able to use the bare all()

Create another classmethod ie. filtered_all()  and use that so that you can keep all() around.

e.g.

```
@classmethod
def filtered_all(cls,keys_only=False) 
    qry = cls.all(keys_only)
    qry.filter('some boolean operation')
    return qry
```

On a separate note, if you have no investment in db, I personally think you should switch to ndb.

Comment: If you are overriding `all` (rather than adding a new `filtered_all`, like in your second example) you probably do need to call `super(Bob, cls).all()`, since `cls.all()` will be infinitely recursive (and so it will raise a `RuntimeError` when it hits the system recursion limit).

Comment: Thanks guys, I won't be able to test the code until Monday but it looks good.  Sadly, I had no say in the technology... the project has been worked on for years I believe, but they lost (fired?) all of the original developers and my employer was contracted to finish the project.  

I'll probably write in a way to access all without the filter, but in this project this specific model will always need to check if its active and it's already written using all() everywhere.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Nevermind about having to wait until Monday to test, I found a way:)  I was able to get it to work, but passing in keys_only on line 3 of your code causes <em>TypeError: all() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)</em>... removing it or setting it to False like the previous line will make it work though.  I'm going to update my post with my functioning code.  Thanks again

Comment: I forgot keys_only is a named argument, I edited the code below to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is right, but because you only have one class, or maybe a handful of classes, you can easily do a search and replace on Bob.all() and change it to Bob.filter(yournewboolean=True).

Any decent text editor or IDE will be able to do this for you in a minute.

Comment: Thanks, but a simple find and replace wouldn't work as some parts already have filters attached and there are thousands of instances... if the replace were to cause a problem it could be very difficult to troubleshoot.  The solution I'm seeking (and it looks like the other answer provides it) would be much simpler to write and troubleshoot.  In most situations, though, I would use this method :)